# Django access MultilinestringM in Postgis with Geometry(dim=3)

Tags: django, django-models, gis, geodjango

I do have Railway-lines using "Linear Referencing" stored as MultilinestringM in a Postgis-DB (created by FME). So each line has a certain code and along that line assets are placed (km_from, km_to). I do need read access only in order to calculate Linestring from the given from-to values.

I try to access that Postgis Information with Django (Geodjango). Does anybody have a clue how to do so? Since in found out Django-Models do not support M-values i thought i try MulitlinestringField with dim=3 and use the z-Dimension which actually would be the m-Dimension.

When accessing the DB I only get 2-dimensional Multilinestring even when setting dim=3.

```py
geom = models.MultiLineStringField(
        dim=3, srid=EPSG_CODE, blank=True, null=True, spatial_index=True
    )  # EPSG:3128=AustriaLambert
```

Does anybody know how I can read in all 3 values from the MultilineStringM stored in Postgis?

Many thanks

Since in found out Django-Models do not support M-values i thought i try MulitlinestringField with dim=3 and use the z-Dimension which actually would be the m-Dimension.

When accessing the DB I only get 2-dimensional Multilinestring even when setting dim=3.